# does the ratio of the count of rational numbers on an $n\times n$ grid to $n^2$, converge as $n$ tends to infinity

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Suppose we order the rational numbers using the diagonal method (used to prove they are countable) using an $n\times n$ grid. Now suppose we count the distinct rational numbers (those points on the grid where gcd(numerator, denominator) = 1. Denote this by $S_n$.

Does $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^2/|S_n|$ exist, and if so what is it?

Some quick computations suggest that it converges to approx 1.64...

Comment: It may not be immediately apparent, but this is not a current research-level problem. Wikipedia says the answer was proven in 1881 and gives as reference Hardy & Wright 2008, Theorem 332.

Comment: thanks for the reference

Comment: I think I don't understand the statement of the problem.  Are you counting rational numbers in a certain box (which one?), or rational numbers on the lattice points of a certain bounded portion of the lattice (in which case the answer seems to be that there are $n^2$)?  I'm sure I'm misunderstanding a clear statement, but maybe I'm not the only one.

Comment: @LSpice The question is asking for *distinct* rational numbers in the bounded section. For example, for $n = 2$ (i.e. on the 4 points), there are 3 distinct rational numbers: $2/1, 1/2, 1/1 = 2/2$.

Comment: @user44191, oh, so we are counting the image of the mapping $(m, n) \mapsto m/n$ from lattice points to rational numbers.  That's what I was missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit you are looking for is the *reciprocal* of the probability that two random positive integers are coprime. This probability (with the proper intepretation) is the density of square-free numbers:
$$\prod_{\text{$p$ is prime}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)=\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{-1}=\frac{6}{\pi^2}.$$
Note that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}=1.6449340668\dots$$